# Using Sequelize with associations and scopes with includes in multiple files

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using [this way](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/models) to keep my Sequelize models in separate files and everything works pretty well but now I came up with the idea to have scopes with includes in it.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {...}, {
  scopes: {
    complete: {
      include: [{
        model: Task
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

... Since Task is (of course) not defined. Even using `require('.').Task` instead doesn't help at this point because `User` gets loaded before `Task` and by the time `User` is loaded, `Task` is not yet defined.

So, is there a simple and easy way without a dozen workarounds to have

- associations
- scopes with includes
- ... All of this in a separate file per model?

Comment: I pretty much had to write my own dependency injection module to handle this issue. Sequelize may be the best ORM mapper for node currently, but it is severely lacking in many areas, IMO

Answer (score 10):

and if the model (Task) is not yet loaded? (in this case T comes before U and the model is loaded).

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

becomes

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("loadScopes" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].loadScopes(db);
  }
});
```

and the model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Task)
      }
    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

becomes

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Task)
      }

      loadScopes: function(models) {
        User.addScope('complete', {
          include: [{
            model: models.Task
          }]
        })
      }

    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the `addScope()` method is better for include models in scope. This is because Sequelize models are defined alphabetically, `Model A` comes first before `Model B`. When you include `Model B` in `Model A` scope, by the time `Model A` runs `Model B` is undefined. `addScope()` method solves this issue.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, { });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Task);

    // scopes should be defined here
    User.addScope('defaultScope', {
      include: [{ model: models.Task }],
    });

    // scopes with parameter
    User.addScope('byProfile', profileId => ({
      where: { profileId },
    }));
  };

  return User;
};
```

using default scope:

`User.findAll();`
This will use the default scope by default.

using `byProfile` scope:

`User.scope({ method: ['byProfile', profile.id] }).findAll();`

Comment: it seems multiple scope are not working for me. https://pastebin.com/4QuS81jE

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Sequelize.models.Task`

```
module.export = function(Sequelize, DataTypes){
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {...}, {
    scopes: {
      complete: {
        include: [{
          model: Sequelize.models.Task
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Or use `addScope()` to add them without having to worry about order of loading each model

Comment: Works fine, awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @ManuelBieh No problem! I'm glad I could help =)

Comment: Well … not quite :( There still seems to be an issue with the order how the models are getting loaded. I'm loading the model files ordered alphabetically. When I rename `Task` to, lets say `Zask`, I get an error since `Zask` is now loaded *after* `User`.

`Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined`. Seems impossible to solve.

Comment: Ooookay, got it! There is a method `addScope()` which can be used in the same way as the `associate` method in the example.